# Error Exception - Undefined variable: session in CodeIgniter4

Tags: codeigniter-4

Session part is not working in my view , showing the exception error..

```
    public function verify()
{
    $this->session = \Config\Services::session();

    $newdata = [
        'username'  => 'johndoe',
        'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
    ];

    $this->session->set($newdata); // setting session data

    return view ('verify');
}
```

In the View

```
<div>
   <?php echo $session->get("username");?>
</div>
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

modify the basecontroller
use Config\Services;

Initialise

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
    {
        $this->session = Services::session();
    }
```

controller

```
$newdata = [
        'username'  => 'johndoe',
        'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
    ];

    session()->set($newdata);
```

in the view

```
<p>
  <?= session('username');?>
  <?= session('email');?>
  <?= session('Logged_in');?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add one file before the Codeigniter 4 execution.

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * LAUNCH THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * Now that everything is setup, it's time to actually fire
 * up the engines and make this app do its thang.
 */
include "id.php"; //<--------
$app->run();
```

The session doesn't work for me if the file contains spaces after the last PHP tag.

```
<?php define('TENANT', 2); ?> //or space here <---
    //<-- space here
```

Try to remove spaces. And remember to add the session start line in the BaseController.

```
    $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
```